# iOS 7 Video PLayer behavior

Tags: video, ios7

I have seen if we play video on **iOS6** , On clicking seek forward button(>>|) in Fullscreen , if there is no next video available , the tap does is sort of ignored and there is no change on the screen.

Where as in **iOS7** , if we click the seek forward button and there is no next video available , the video screen closes.

Is this a bug in iOS7 or the default functionality which has been changed in iOS7.

Any one, please help!

Comment: Can anyone please help. Its really urgent.. I have spent hours on this.. but could not confirm whether its a bug or done on purpose. And if it done On purpose , I would like to know how to handle if next video track is available or not?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that it is reverting back to the start of the playlist in iOS7, where it was 'unable' to in iOS6.

Not sure if this is on purpose though or if it will get fixed, but it is frustrating.

Comment: Scatterly Cow : Do you know how to handle next video track available functionality?